# Horizontal layout in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I would like to place the label and comboBox horizontally aligned, but by default it is vertically aligned, please suggest

```
<div >              
    <label >Attribute:</label>
    <select>                    
        <option id="day" value="month">Day</option>
        <option id="week" value="week">Week</option>
        <option id="month" value="month">Month</option>                         
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it the `display` property will be set to `block`, you can try to change it to `inline-block`

```
label, select {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following CSS:

```
div
{
    display: flex;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/PhoenixMobiplanet/d5634/